# Overlapping indexes in App Engine -- Ok to combine them?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a query that relies on the first index below. Recently, another part of my app needs to run a similar query; the only difference is that it also needs to filter by the `name` property as well.

Original index:

```
- kind: Achievement
  properties:
  - name: region
  - name: date_earned
    direction: desc
```

Proposed additional index for new query:

```
- kind: Achievement
  properties:
  - name: name
  - name: region
  - name: date_earned
    direction: desc
```

Given that the original query overlaps with the second query (i.e. they both query `region` and `date_earned` in descending order), do I need to keep two indexes, as seen above?

Or am I able to combine these two indexes, since the first query overlaps with the second? In other words, if I eliminate the first index, will my original query that only queries by `region` and `date_earned` still function without throwing an `NeedIndexError`?

The goal is to reduce the number of indexes I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For datastore indexes, in your case , if you have an index for :

- kind: Achievement
  properties:

  - name: name
  - name: region
  - name: date_earned
    direction: desc

You can query for 1 or more properties (that form the index )  in the same GQL query .
So you can query any combination of 1 or more of the properties : 'name', 'region', 'date_earned'.

Also a good way to confirm if you need an index would be to run the GQL query in your App Engine app's datastore viewer . So if you have an index for 'name', 'region', 'date_earned', you can run your GQL query and confirm that you dont need a seperate index.

Comment: This answer is correct, but in the case of an explicit sort order, you may need a separate query. The GQL technique worked well in helping diagnose this. Thanks!